# PowerPivot fiter to slice data per hour, day or month

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have an `Excel` database file that contains the total passenger passes from a specific location. The total number of passenger passes is counted in a period of 2 minutes(e.g. 14:45:00 to 14:46:59). I have imported my database into `PowerPivot` and have also created relevant `PivotTables` and `PivotCharts` with some slicers to analyze them. How can I create a slicer which filters data in greater periods of time like hour, day or month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a Date/time table which contains all hours in your data.

First you'll need to create a calculated column in your original data that has the date and the hour

Formula to use:

```
=DATE(YEAR([Original Date]),MONTH([Original Date]),DAY([Original Date]))+HOUR([Original Date])/24
```

Result in your original data table

```
Original Date         Calculated_DateHour
02/15/2015 14:15      02/15/2015 14:00
02/15/2015 16:25      02/15/2015 16:00
```

Now, in Excel create a Master Date table with unique date/time for all data

```
[DateTable]
Master_DateHour    Year    Month   Day   Hour
02/15/2015 13:00   2015    2       15    13
02/15/2015 14:00   2015    2       15    14
02/15/2015 15:00   2015    2       15    15
02/15/2015 16:00   2015    2       15    16
02/15/2015 17:00   2015    2       15    17
{...}
03/17/2015 02:00   2015    3       17    2
```

Next you'll create a relationship between the `DateTable[Master_DateHour]` (lookup table) and `Data[Calculated_DateHour]`.

Now you should be able to slice based on the Year/Month/Day/Hour as you see fit.

Additionally, you could create a hierarchy in the `[DateTable]` to give you more control over the presentation of Year/Month/Day/Hour.

Comment: How can I create a Master Date table? By hand? There are more than 100k entries and still growing.

Comment: You start with your earliest date/hour, then pick some date/hour in the future and use formulas in the Year/Month/Day/Hour columns to extrapolate each part